# Error: [ProxyFacade] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using  "react-router-dom": "6.0.2" in React 17. And i am using typescript. I am tried to add route. But getting error

**Uncaught Error: [ProxyFacade] is not a  component. All component children of  must be a  or <React.Fragment>**

And i don't know what was the issue.Is anything i missed.

**App.tsx**

```
import * as React from "react";
import "./index.less";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import { hot } from "react-hot-loader";
import SignIn from "../sign-in";
import SignUp from "../sign-up";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<SignIn />} />
        <Route path="/signup" element={<SignUp />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
declare let module: Record<string, unknown>;

export default hot(module)(App);
```

**sign-in/index.tsx**

```
import * as React from "react";
const SignIn = () => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>
        <p>Sign In</p>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default SignIn;
```

**sign-up/index.tsx**

```
import * as React from "react";
const SignUp = () => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>
        <p>Sign In</p>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default SignUp;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might have something to do with the react hot loader. The hot loader wraps everything with proxies[hence the `[ProxyFacade]` in the error]. And probably the React router code looks at the type of the function(component) to verify if the `Routes` has any children other than `Route` component. See the issue [here](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/issues/1311).

You can try first without the hot reloader to see if you still face the issue. If you don't then you can fix the react hot loader issue as mentioned in the link I added above.

Comment: Sure @akshay sehgal , Will try this

Comment: Did it work? I am facing the same issue.. but it doesn’t seem to be related to Hot so I don’t know.. thanks

Comment: removing hot module fixed it for me