# Uncaught Error: [ProxyFacade] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, react-router-dom, hot-module-replacement

I am using webpack with router v6

```
import React from 'react';
import { hot } from 'react-hot-loader';
import Layout from '@cmp/Layout';
import Main from '@pages/Main';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="/"
          element={
            <Layout>
              <Main />
            </Layout>
          }
        />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

// export default App;
export default hot(module)(App);
```

and I am encountering this error.

There is a [stackoverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70037167/error-proxyfacade-is-not-a-route-component-all-component-children-of-rout) for this but it does not seem to be working for me. Please help me to solve this error.